# Does anyone know where I can find android's ICS home button's code?

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-button

I want to be able to modify that code to make it into double tap instead of a single tap. The reason is that it's too close the the space button on the screen on my phone. I always end up tapping it accidentally when pressing the space key or using an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in [PhoneWindowManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java). These lines may be what you are looking for:

```
1821        // First we always handle the home key here, so applications
1822        // can never break it, although if keyguard is on, we do let
1823        // it handle it, because that gives us the correct 5 second
1824        // timeout.
1825        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
1826
1827            // If we have released the home key, and didn't do anything else
1828            // while it was pressed, then it is time to go home!
1829            if (!down) {
1830                final boolean homeWasLongPressed = mHomeLongPressed;
1831                mHomePressed = false;
1832                mHomeLongPressed = false;
1833                if (!homeWasLongPressed) {
1834                    if (mLongPressOnHomeBehavior == LONG_PRESS_HOME_RECENT_SYSTEM_UI) {
1835                        try {
```

Comment: Or https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java